# What is a concise way to test outputs of a function in java?

Tags: java

Is there a easy way to chain the testable function calls into a concise block to run and increment a score when the test comes back positive? The following is the class to test.

```
public class Weather{
  public Weather(float temp, int day, int month, int year){}
  public float getTemp(){}
  public void setCelsius(){}
  public void setFahrenheit(){}
  public boolean isCelsius(){}
  public String toString(){}

}
```

A typical test case consists of setting the celsius, and fahrenheit, getting the value, and match the string.

```
Weather testMe = new Weather(100.6f, 31, 7, 1997);
if(testMe.toString().equals("July 31, 1997. Temperature is 100.60 C.")) { score+=1}
if(testMe.getTemp() == 100.6f) {score+=1}
if(testMe.isCelcius()) {score+=1;}
testMe.setFahrenheit();
if(testMe.toString().equals("July 31, 1997. Temperature is 213.08 F.")) { score+=1}
if(testMe.getTemp() == 213.08f) {score+=1}
if(!testMe.isCelcius()) {score+=1;}
testMe.setCelcius();
if(testMe.isCelcius()) {score+=1;}
```

I could repeat this over and over again, but can this testing can be shortened?

Comment: use a library that provides assert() functions. learning to use a library like JUnit is worth the effort if you're serious about using Java, better than rolling your own bc of IDE support

Comment: Try not to write one line if statements, they don't make the code clear

Comment: I wonder if you could write a Junit runner that tracks the score. Maybe you even annotate test methods with `@Score(value=1)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the scoring system is not the right way to measure the correctness of the code. a test should have only two states. passed or failed. so by scoring you cannnot achieve this.

u can use JUnit to test the code. write all possible test cases using JUnit and run the test. then you will know whether your code passed or failed.

to start learning about JUnit u can go throw some basic tutorials like [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj349OA0q3LAhUBwo4KHddBCe4QFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tutorialspoint.com%2Fjunit%2F&usg=AFQjCNFQ1lLJEpInxZOhGANebhScb7pB3A&sig2=9PnoSAsluyw5TNK-2jLx1Q)

Answer (score 0):

There's really not a lot of "extra" boilerplate besides actually incrementing the score. If that's what you're trying to avoid, you can make a simple method for that:

```
int score = 0;

void test(boolean condition) {
    if (condition) {
        score++;
    }
}
```

Then in your scoring method call

```
test(testMe.toString().equals("July 31, 1997. Temperature is 100.60 C."));
test(testMe.getTemp() == 100.6f);
test(testMe.isCelcius());
...
```